# How to tell when the Shield UI has loaded?

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am using the Shield UI Charting javascript component. Is there a way to determine when the control has finished loading on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is an event- events, that occurs after the chart has loaded completely. This is especially important when dealing with remote data, which can take some more time, compared to the loading time of the chart itself. Below is an example of using the load event:

```
events: {
   load: function(event) {
       alert("Chart has finished Loading");
   }
}
```